# Jquery: How to obtain attribute from content

Tags: javascript, jquery, database

I am having trouble obtaining an element from a content and displaying it when the user clicks their mouse.

Basically, we are making a lost and found website, and when the user clicks on a specific location, we want a text box to appear with the name of the location.

We have a problem where nothing gets outputted, or a long url, or sometimes [Object object]

```
content: <area id="AF' class="location" title="Anderson Field" alt="Anderson Field">
```

We have multiple area attributes with the same class name but the ID is different. Instead of tediously saying if (id == "AF") print "Anderson Field", we want to automatically get the value depending on the mouse click

Our event handler:

```
$("href").click("click", function(){
```

`$("#textBox").val(myfunction();`

```
function myfunction()
{
  return $("input").val(title);
}
```

so our myfunction is actually getting the value of the attribute, but our problem is we are not getting it correctly. Either nothing shows, a long url, or [Object object]

Comment: `return $("input").val(title);` if that's trying to get the title, that needs to be more like `return $("input")[0].title;` - though, "input" is wrong here too

Comment: thank you @Jaromanda this actually helped us a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event to the "area" element inside of the map, and from the jQuery event access the element properties (of the "area" element), via the ["this" keyword](https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified).

Assuming your map is called "planetmap", for example, it could be:

```
$("map[name=planetmap] area").on("click", function(){
    $("#textBox").val($(this).attr('title')).show();
    return false;
});
```

Where textBox is the hidden input you want to display. You can see it live:

https://jsfiddle.net/zetxek/rs03e3zd/5/

In case you just want to set the value of the input and display it in some other part of the code, you can omit the "show" part:

```
$("#textBox").val($(this).attr('title'));
```

Comment: why the `id`? isn't it the `title` the question is asking for?

Comment: I got confused with the title and id being the same in the element - but let's use the title instead:

Comment: title and id are not the same in the element at all "AF" !== "Anderson Field"  it's actually the `title` and the `alt` that are the same

Comment: D'oh - you're totally right. I misread that part and skipped directly to write the code. I hope the example is more clear now by using the title attribute, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your input! So, does the "this" keyword get the element from the mouse click? For example, our map is numbered 1-35, where each number presents a different part on campus. So 1 is the Anderson Field we are trying to access.

With jaromanda's suggestion with using: $("input")[0].title; we got the title, but when we click on 2 or 3, they will all show "anderson Field"

Comment: Exactly. This is a jQuery keyword dependant on the context. In your function, this will be the element that received the click - so you can use it to retrieve its attributes.